# Setting variable with RxJs tap operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been had difficulties in setting the variable `awaiting_response` (below) to true (it doesn't set), using `tap()` from RxJs.

A hacky solution was made by setting outside the `pipe()` but I imagine it's not ideal.

The same code can be viewed [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-0-0-css)

Here is the `component.ts`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject, of } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, tap, switchMap, catchError, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ServiceApiService, ITemp } from "./service-api.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  protected addresses: Observable<ITemp[]>;
  private search_term: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  protected executing_search: boolean = false;
  protected awaiting_response: boolean = false;

  constructor(private search: ServiceApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addresses = this.search_term.pipe(
      debounceTime(3500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => (this.awaiting_response = true)),
      tap(() => () => console.log("awaiting", this.awaiting_response)),
      switchMap((term: string) =>
        this.search.search_addresses(term).pipe(
          catchError(() => of<ITemp[]>([]))
          //finalize(() => setTimeout(() => (this.awaiting_response = false), 0))
        )
      ),
      tap(() => (this.awaiting_response = false)),
      tap(() => console.log("awaiting", this.awaiting_response)),
      tap(() => (this.executing_search = false))
      //finalize(() => (this.awaiting_response = false))
    );
  }

  execute_search() {
    this.executing_search = true;
    this.search_term.next("term");
  }
}
```

The `service`

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subscriber } from "rxjs";

export interface ITemp {
  value: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceApiService {
  constructor() {}

  search_addresses(term: string): Observable<ITemp[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
      observer.next([{ value: `response: ${new Date().toString()}` }]);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

And the `component.html`

```html
<button (click)="execute_search()">Search</button>
<div>Awaiting: {{awaiting_response | json}}</div>
<div>Executing {{executing_search | json}}</div>
<div>Response: {{addresses | async | json}}
```

Comment: What’s the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is your code should work as expected.

Here is the explanation. 
Your `awaiting_response` is setting to true but you won't be able to see the difference as the `observer` in your service is emitting values instantly

To show the difference I have set a `timeout` in the service as below,

```
search_addresses(term: string): Observable<ITemp[]> {
    return Observable
    .create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next([{ value: `response: ${new Date().toString()}` }]);
        observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
    });
}
```

you can see the difference in this [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-0-0-css-1h1jav)

Comment: Ahhh I get it now, I thought `debounceTime` does not apply to `tap`, huge mistake.

Comment: `debounceTime` is different from `timeout` @ArKan

Answer (score 3):

You just can't see the log, replace

```js
tap(() => () => console.log("awaiting", this.awaiting_response))
```

to

```js
tap(() => console.log("awaiting", this.awaiting_response))
```

Comment: Oops, my bad, so that was making debugging so difficult, nice one